# open the Windows virtual keyboard in a Java program

Tags: java, keyboard, virtual

I would like to create an event in a button.

When I click in the button, I would like to open the Windows virtual keyboard.

Can you help me with the code?

Thank you for your collaboration.

Best regards.

Comment: What code have you written and tried so far?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it would be as simple as this:
`Runtime.getRuntime().exec("osk");`

Comment: How to make the OSK with Java (not just execute OSK, because it has some dangerous keys)

Answer (score 4):

You can use getRuntime to execute it:

```
import java.io.IOException;

public class ShowVirtualKeyboard{

    public static void main(String argv[]) throws IOException {
    String sysroot = System.getenv("SystemRoot");
    Process proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(sysroot + "/system32/osk.exe");
}
}
```

and you can call `proc.destroy()` to get rid of it.

Regards.

Answer (score 1):

This will work: `Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c osk");`

`cmd /c` will launch the process and invoke the UAC if needed.

Advantage:

- And it would avoid privileges issue.

Disadvantage:

- Would not be able to turn off by Process instance on java.

Comment: Anyone know how to open the other virtual keyboard in Windows, not osk? The one for tablets?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is a little bit late but if you cannot manage to close the keyboard too, this answer may help you https://stackoverflow.com/a/71410876/12346089

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31249922)